# How can I set the default timezone in Lua?

Tags: lua, timezone

can i set default timezone in Lua just like in PHP

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
$Year = date('y');
$Month = date('m');
$Day = date('d');
$Hour = date('H');
$Minute = date('i');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to set it by Environment with start of Lua.
On an Unix like operating system i mean this...

```
€ date
Do 7. Apr 07:25:53 CEST 2022
€ env -i TZ=Europe/London lua -e "print(os.date())"
Thu Apr  7 06:26:47 2022
€ env -i TZ=Europe/Berlin lua -e "print(os.date())"
Thu Apr  7 07:26:58 2022
```

But feel free to write a time module.
Could look like...

```
€ env -i TZ=Europe/London lua -e "tzdate = setmetatable({}, {__index = {Berlin = function() return os.date(_, os.time() + 3600) end}}) print(tzdate.Berlin())"
Thu Apr  7 07:41:03 2022
```

And without `env -i TZ=` with @Egor Skriptunoff' hint a simple, hm, how could it be called, maybe Prototype?

```
$ /bin/lua -i
Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> tzdate = setmetatable({[0] = 7200}, {__tostring = function(self) return os.date('!%c', os.time() + self[#self]) end})
> print(tzdate)
Thu Apr  7 20:42:01 2022
> tzdate[1]=3600
> print(tzdate)
Thu Apr  7 19:42:43 2022
> tzdate[2]=7200
> print(tzdate)
Thu Apr  7 20:43:21 2022
```

This works while autoconverting `tostring()` is done by `print()`.
To get the value in a variable or do other things that do no autoconverting use therefore `tostring()`...

```
> tzdate[3]=10800
> io.write(tzdate)
stdin:1: bad argument #1 to 'write' (string expected, got table)
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'write'
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
> io.write(tostring(tzdate), '\n')
Thu Apr  7 21:59:40 2022
```

Comment: You can simplify the last example by avoiding setting London `TZ`.  Just replace date format `_` with UTC-style `!%c`.  This way the output will be independent of the current timezone of your system.